# Tastypie 'Search' Only Returns Resource Name

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I'm trying to create a function that filters objects by a ForeingKey field (or rather the object being referenced in the field). I wrote the function which I have included below, which is based off the Tastypie Cookbook's Adding Search Functionality. The function does work in that it returns the objects, however it only returns the objects' names as a string.

This is the result of calling the function:

`{'receipt_items': [<ReceiptItem: Item1>, <ReceiptItem: Item2>, <ReceiptItem: Item3>]}`

Here is my resource:

```
class ReceiptItemResource(ModelResource):
receipt = fields.ToOneField(ReceiptResource, 'receipt', full = True)
class Meta:
    queryset = ReceiptItem.objects.all()
    serializer = Serializer()
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
    always_return_data = True

def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/filter%s$' % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('filter_by_receipt'), name = 'filter_by_receipt'),

        ]

def filter_by_receipt(self, request, **kwargs):
    data = self.deserialize(request, request.body, format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    receipt_id = data.get('receipt_id', '')
    print receipt_id

    receipt = Receipt.objects.get(id = receipt_id)

    receipt_items = ReceiptItem.objects.filter(receipt = receipt)

    item_list = {
        'receipt_items' : receipt_items,
    }

    print item_list
    return self.create_response(request, receipt_items)

    #return super(ReceiptItemResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(receipt = receipt)

def get_object_list(self, request):
    user = request.user
    member = user.member
    owner = member.owner


    return super(ReceiptItemResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(owner = owner)
```

Ideally I would like this function to return the full object details in JSON. Is there any way to make this happen?

I have looked into Tastypie's resource filtering, however I don't believe this would work since the field I am trying to filter by is a ForeignKey.

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do this. You can filter on foreignKey by default using the filtering option

```
from tastypie.resources import ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS

class RecieptResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta: 
       fields = ["id"]
       filtering = {
         "id": ALL
       }

class ReceiptItemResource(ModelResource):
    receipt = fields.ToOneField(ReceiptResource, 'receipt', full = True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = ReceiptItem.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            "reciept": ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

Now the following should url (depending on how you have yours configured) should give you what you want

/api/v1/reciept-item/?receipt__id=1&format=json

Comment: That returns `ImportError: cannot import name All_WITH_RELATIONS`, I can't seem to find anything online about this error.

Comment: Its a typo... make it ALL_WITH_RELATIONS instead of All_WITH_RELATIONS

Comment: That fixed the import error however now that that is working I am getting a `No JSON object could be decoded error`.

Comment: Try removing the 'serializer = Serializer()' line. The serializer should be set by default. I made the changed to the quoted code.

Comment: After trying that the issue persists unfortunately.